# NoneType Error in Lambda layer while applying a mask to a tensor

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I have dataset X of 2D images, and I divided it into batches X_1, ..., X_k. Then for each i-th component of a batch element, I want to multiply it by parameter gamma_i and add beta_i to them.

**Error:**

```
Input reshape: (4, 12, 12, 1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "3.py", line 61, in <module>
    model = build_test((i, 12, 12, 1))
  File "3.py", line 49, in build_test
    x = Lambda(lambda tensor, mask: tf.math.multiply(tensor, tf.convert_to_tensor(mask, dtype=tf.float32)))([input_img, gamma])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 634, in __call__
    outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/core.py", line 785, in call
    return self.function(inputs, **arguments)
  File "3.py", line 49, in <lambda>
    x = Lambda(lambda tensor, mask: tf.math.multiply(tensor, tf.convert_to_tensor(mask, dtype=tf.float32)))([input_img, gamma])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1087, in convert_to_tensor
    return convert_to_tensor_v2(value, dtype, preferred_dtype, name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1145, in convert_to_tensor_v2
    as_ref=False)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1224, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 305, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 246, in constant
    allow_broadcast=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 284, in _constant_impl
    allow_broadcast=allow_broadcast))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 454, in make_tensor_proto
    raise ValueError("None values not supported.")
ValueError: None values not supported.
```

You can reproduce the error using the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Input, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Lambda, Multiply, Add, Reshape
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
import numpy as np

def build_test(input_shape):
    input_img = Input(shape=input_shape)
    print('Input reshape:', input_shape)

    x = Lambda(lambda tensor, mask: tf.math.multiply(tensor, tf.convert_to_tensor(mask, dtype=tf.float32)))([input_img, gamma])
    print('multiply:', x.shape)
    x = Lambda(lambda tensor, mask: tf.math.add(tensor, tf.convert_to_tensor(mask, dtype=tf.float32)))([x, beta])
    print('add:', x.shape)

    test = Model(inputs=input_img, outputs=x)
    return test

batch_sizes = [4, 8]
for i in batch_sizes:
    gamma = np.arange(i)
    beta = np.arange(i)
    model = build_test((i, 12, 12, 1))
```

However when I use the following code which indirectly solves my purpose is working fine:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Input, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Lambda, Multiply, Add, Reshape
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
import numpy as np

def build_test(input_shape):
    input_img = Input(shape=input_shape)
    print('Input reshape:', input_shape)

    for batch in range(input_shape[0]):
        # x = tf.gather(x, batch)
        # print('tensor shape:', x.shape)  
        mask = np.empty(input_shape, dtype=np.float32)
        # for gamma
        mask.fill(1)
        mask[batch].fill(gamma[batch])
        x = Lambda(lambda tensor: tf.math.multiply(tensor, tf.convert_to_tensor(mask, dtype=tf.float32)))(input_img)
        print('multiply:', x.shape)
        # for beta
        mask.fill(1)
        mask[batch].fill(beta[batch])
        x = Lambda(lambda tensor: tf.math.add(tensor, tf.convert_to_tensor(mask, dtype=tf.float32)))(x)
        print('add:', x.shape)

    test = Model(inputs=input_img, outputs=x)
    return test

batch_sizes = [4, 8]
for i in batch_sizes:
    gamma = np.arange(i)
    beta = np.arange(i)
    model = build_test((i, 12, 12, 1))
```

What am I doing wrong in the former code for which I am getting the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the former code, while initialization, mask was not declared before and hence the tensor value for it was empty and giving error.

Since in the latter code, you have initialized it, it worked fine.